# Search not exists in Django

Tags: python, database, django, list, filter

I'm really new to django programming, and I'm facing a problem I don't really know how to solve:

I want to get a list of users who have many string attributes, but only the users whom none of it's attributes is equal to a given one.

I have this piece of code

```
all_users = list(UserProfile.objects.attribute.filter(type=given).exists())
```

but this code will return me the users who have that attribute, **so here's the question**: How I can modify this line (or what lines do I need to add) in order to get the list of users without this attribute

Ps: Maybe I didn't explained myself clearly as I don't really know how to specify my problem in english, but, if you don't know what I'm asking I can try again

Thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters):

```
all_users = list(UserProfile.objects.attribute.exclude(type=given).exists())
```

To quote the docs:

> To create such a subset, you refine the initial QuerySet, adding filter conditions. The two most common ways to refine a QuerySet are:
>
> `filter(**kwargs)`
>   Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters.
>
> `exclude`(**kwargs)
>   Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that do not match the given lookup parameters.